# ScrollViews and Segmented controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

This is really odd, but I have a segmented controller and both of the views have a scroll view. So when you click on one half of the segmented controller that view has a scroll view, and the other half also has a scroll view. For some bizarre reason only one of the views will scroll. I need them both to scroll. Does this made sense?

Comment: Do both scroll views have the content you expect them to have? When you show the one that won't scroll, have you checked its `.contentSize`? Is it being set by code or constraints? Are you adding subviews to the scroll views dynamically via code or all in Interface Builder? What is a "segmented controller"? Something you wrote or someone else's code? (as you might guess, you need to provide much more information)

Comment: everything is made in the interface builder . Segmented controller: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTjYU.png

Comment: hmmm? The image you linked to shows what appears to be a table view, not a scroll view... and there is no content in the table view to scroll?

Comment: The image was to show you what a segmented controller looks like

Comment: do you mean that you use scroll views inside of the segmented control? in the picture you provided, would that scroll views be in the segmented control instead of those titles ('All', 'Not on this iPhone')?
Also, the code in question might be helpful..

Comment: @Jaqueline - ok.. so when you tap on one segment, do you bring a subview to the front? do you show one subview and hide the other? do you load a child view controller and replace the current view?

Comment: ...It isn't possible to have a scroll view inside of a segmented controller. The picture that was provided was not my app, it was an image pulled from google so that DonMag can see what a segmented controller is. It is just the bar that says "all, Not on this iPhone" when it is on either controls it has a scroll view.

Comment: Yes I would like to have it so when you click on one segmented control it adds a subview to the view and gets rid of the other subview added previously.

Comment: @Jaqueline - ummm... very confusing. You say you *"have a segmented controller and both of the views have a scroll view."* But you are not explaining ***how*** you are showing the views, or what they look like, or how you are determining that they *should* be scrolling.

Comment: When the value of the segmented controller = 0 it shows one view which is a scroll view, and when the segmented controller = 1 it shows a different view which is also a scroll view.

Comment: OK - so back to my original question... Are you checking the `.contentSize`? You say *"everything is made in the interface builder"* --- so are you using constraints to define the scrollable content?

Comment: Yes. I haven't set up the view at all programmatically. All of it is in the interface builder with constraints, etc.

Comment: Are you following me now? Let me know what other information I need to give you.

Comment: @Jaqueline - I am trying to help you, but you need to provide complete information. You wrote *"when the segmented controller = 1 it shows a different view"* ... but you don't say ***how*** it shows the different view. Does it toggle `.isHidden` property? Does it add it as a new subview? Does it bring it to front? If you swap your scroll views, does the 2nd one now scroll and the 1st one doesn't, or still the 1st scrolls and 2nd doesn't?

Comment: Thank you so much for that idea, it ended up working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in the `viewDidLoad` I added a subview for both of them. Then I added an if else statement with `.isHidden` and that works beautifully.